# Can not ssh from a remote docker container on a remote host

Tags: docker, ssh

A container is running on Host A. On Host A, I can ssh to the docker container. On other Hosts, like B, C, D, etc..., I can not ssh to that container.

Are there any hints? All firewalld is disabled

Comment: `docker ps <container_name>`,checkout what ports your container expose?and could you show us what command or other detail yout used to ssh to the container A?

Comment: Docker containers don't normally run ssh daemons.  (A container wraps a single process; if you say "from host B, I can't ssh into crond on host A" that wouldn't really make sense, and roughly the same holds for containers.)  Do you have a [mcve] or any source code relevant to your problem?